# What is the Meaning of '//' in a URL address

Tags: url

I came across an URL (http://www.someurl.com//books/category:10000/) where I encountered '//' as a part of the URL.

What is the meaning of '//' in a URL. Also please provide some use cases where such an entry is made. And if possible please do provide some resources where I can read more about URL structures.

Comment: Most of the time I encounter something like this, it was my bad serverside programming ;)

Comment: Duplicate (at webmasters): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls

Answer (score 1):

Multiple consecutive slashes are commonly ignored, though some web servers may treat them specially.  It's probably implementation specific.  If it is part of the standard, it's loosely followed.

This question: [What is the Meaning of '//' in a URL address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928527/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-url-address/12928627#12928627)

This question with a few extra slashes: https://stackoverflow.com//////questions//////12928527///what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-url-address/12928627#12928627

[Here's a question about the significance of extra slashes on the Webmasters stack exchange site.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls)